# JavaScript DateFormat Conversion

Tags: javascript, datepicker, date-format

I have a the locale and a date in that locale format stored in a var in JavaScript
I need to convert that locale based date string to another local format

I have
locale : en-GB            / en-US            / es         / ko

date   : dd/mm/yyyy       / mm/dd/yyyy       yyyy.mm.dd

the above mentioned formats are not exact
ijust mean they are different for each

not i want that date to be displayed as "August 01 2013" like this

SO Finally i need a function(fromLocale,ToLocale,dateInFromLocaleFormat) which returns Date in ToLocale format

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Please show you existing JavaScript code. Are you saying that the input date is in a known format, or that it could be any one of the three you show but you won't know which?

Comment: It could be any format and i can get that any format and its Locale.
Now i have to use that locale info and parse the given date and generate a date in en_US locale

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the JavaScript function `dateFormat` and set the format manually when you display the date?

for example: `dateFormat("date", "mmmm dd yyyy");`

more detailed here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Note that `dateFormat()` isn't a built in JS function.

Comment: When the input is mm/dd/yyyy en_US everything works good.
When the input is dd/mm/yyyy en_GB Date.parse() thinks its in mm/dd/yyy
and returns me a wrong answer

so i need something like function(localeFrom,localeTO,<dateFormatein FromLocale>)